# C# Regex not matching empty string

Tags: c#, regex

I am using the following to match a line. A Line could somthing like below. For instance if field1 is present but the value is null, it doesnt match.  I want it to match even if field1 or etc has blank or no value. Any ideas? thanks

```
   field33
   field1 
   field2   lkjk
   field3   12.01.12

 static string partPattern = @"^(?<Key>\w+)\s+(?<Value>.*)$";

 line = line.Trim();  Match m = Regex.Match(line, partPattern);  
if(m.Groups["Key"].Length > 0) { 
 //do something heree 
}
```

so when it looks at field33, line becomes  field33 and the regex conditional statment fails even though key is there...

Comment: When you say "Does not match" or "is not doing"...what exactly are you attempting to do with this regex? Code examples would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex patterns, `+` indicates `One or More`.

Try using this string instead

```
@"^(?<Key>\w+)\s+(?<Value>.*)$
```

The `*` indicates `Any Number` including 0.

**Update**

I tested the following code, and got this output.

```
        string t1 = "field1   ";
        string t2 = "field2   iopoi";
        string t3 = "field3   12.12.12";
        Regex rTest = new Regex(@"^(?<Key>\w+)\s+(?<Value>.*)$");
        if (rTest.IsMatch(t1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("T1 match");
            foreach (Match m in rTest.Matches(t1))
                textBox1.Text += String.Format("Key: {0}\tValue: {1}\r\n", m.Groups["Key"].Value, m.Groups["Value"].Value);
        }
        textBox1.Text += "\n\n";
        if (rTest.IsMatch(t2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("T2 match");
            foreach (Match m in rTest.Matches(t2))
                textBox1.Text += String.Format("Key: {0}\tValue: {1}\r\n", m.Groups["Key"].Value, m.Groups["Value"].Value);
        }
        textBox1.Text += "\n\n";
        if (rTest.IsMatch(t3))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("T3 match");
            foreach (Match m in rTest.Matches(t3))
                textBox1.Text += String.Format("Key: {0}\tValue: {1}\r\n", m.Groups["Key"].Value, m.Groups["Value"].Value);
        }
```

Output:

```
Key: field1 Value: 
Key: field2 Value: iopoi
Key: field3 Value: 12.12.12
```

I also tested this code calling `.Trim()` on each initial string.

t1 DID NOT MATCH after calling `.Trim()`

The reason for this, is because .Trim removes all the whitespace following field1, or field33, or whatever, and the regex requires `One or More` whitespace characters.

**New Regex:** Try using this instead `@"^(?<Key>\w+)\s*(?<Value>.*)$"`

Note that now the \s is also followed by a *.  Now it should match after using Trim as well.

Comment: In my testing, this regex matched on all 3 lines.  Not sure what else to say to that, what are you trying to do that this is not accomplishing?